# Google Analytics Event Tracking code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm using Google Analytics, at the top level I can see who has come onto my site, however I cannot see track my event tracking for my social network buttons, I think I may have developed these wrong.

These events are not been tracked on my analytics account that I can see anyway if someone knows where they are kept that would be great.

But the code I've used is below as I'm not sure if I have implemented this correctly:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=2009:%20Michael%20Jackson%20Dies&hashtags=DIGITL,MichaelJackson" target="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social Media', 'Twitter', 'Share 2009 Jackson',, false]);"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png" id="2009_michaeljackson_share_twitter" alt="Share on Twitter" title="Share on Twitter"></a>
```

If someone can advise if this is correct will be great!

### Update

As per the answer below, I removed the double comma  retested in the Events Overview section and no on click items have appeared...

Example of updated code:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social Media', 'Facebook', 'Share 2003', false]);"><img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_share_fb" alt="Share Icon for Twitter" title="Share on Facebook"></a></li>
```

I've even added them as a goal in Google Analytics but this doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2665210?hl=en might have more information

Comment: Which version of Analytics are you using, Classic Analytics (using the ga.js) or the Universal one (using analytics.js)? The syntax for the two when it comes to tracking events are different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using the **OLD GOOGLE ANALYTICS TRACKING BLOCK**, then the below should work:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social Media', 'Facebook', 'Share 2003', false]);"><img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_share_fb" alt="Share Icon for Twitter" title="Share on Facebook"></a></li>
```

If you are using the **NEW GOOGLE UNIVERSAL EVENT TRACKING** code the below will work:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Social Media', 'Facebook', 'Share 2003');"><img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_share_fb" alt="Share Icon for Twitter" title="Share on Facebook"></a></li>
```

To check whether the events are firing correctly VERY QUICKLY. Do the following;

**1.** Make sure you update the code on your site and make it live

**2.** Make sure your IP is not excluded or filtered out of the analytis profile

**3.** Login to your google analytics account

**4.** Go to **Real-Time** section on the left hand sidebar.

**5.** Click on **Events**

**6.** Go to your site and click on the link you added the event code to and then watch if that link shows up in the *real-time -> events* section.

**Bounce Rate Discussion**

About the bounce rate everyone is talking about. Usually when you add an event and someone clicks on it, then google analytics will assume that user interacted with your site and therefore provide a very low bounce rate for that page. If you don;t want the bounce rate to be affected on the page where the event is placed, then you can add the false at the end of the event. I would suggest you get the event tracking working, before trying to adjust the bounce rates :-)

Thank you,

Comment: Optimizer thank you! that worked perfectly. I guess I was using the new GA tracking system.

Comment: how come they don't appear in the events overview section?

Comment: They do - but it was difficult for me to find as well. Here it is:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Event Tracking the page needs the basic tracking code for Google Analytics. So I'm assuming this page is tagged with a code similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

This is the Classic Analytics Tracking Code. There's also a chance that you are using a newer version of Analytics called "[Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en)". That version has a different tracking code and the [event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) also has a different syntax. In case you are using Universal Analytics tracking code the event below won't work.

The [`_trackEvent`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEventTracking) method takes 5 parameters:

- String Category
- String Action
- String Label
- Number Value (optional)
- Boolean Non-Interactive (optional)

All of them are positional arguments so in case you want to provide the non-interactive flag you have to pass a value or undefined. Any of the following options are valid and similar.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social Media', 'Facebook', 'Share 2003', undefined, false]);
```

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social Media', 'Facebook', 'Share 2003', 0,false]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick read of the Analytics documentation.

You have a double comma when you're pushing and the fourth part is optional.

So you can remove the ',, false' from your _gaq.push.

Let me know if that helps

**Updated for his update**

Try this code in place of yours. Let me know if it works.

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social Media', 'Facebook', 'Share 2003']);"><img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_share_fb" alt="Share Icon for Twitter" title="Share on Facebook"></a></li>
```

Comment: thanks I've now changed to the following `<li><a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Social Media', 'Facebook', 'Share 2003', false]);"><img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_share_fb" alt="Share Icon for Twitter" title="Share on Facebook"></a></li>` however this still hasn't worked

Comment: @gutigrewal, I've updated my answer with a code snippet, could you try that instead of yours and let me know if it works?

Comment: I've replaced my code with yours, as far as I can see you've removed the false? This means that this will include this into my bounce rate thought right?? As far as I can see this has made a difference to my events section in GA yet

Comment: @gutigrewal: How do you mean "this will include this into my bounce rate?" If an event is triggered without the boolean setting non_interact set to true, an event would make your visitors count outside of your bounce rate as an interactive hit has occured, meaning that they would NOT be counted towards bounce rate.

Answer (score 0):

As well as this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2665210?hl=en) to general tracking on events guide, the following is from the official GA docs. The following line is only a few lines down the page, just under the "overview" header:

> [For example, you might want to measure how many times a button was pressed](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Hope this helps!

Amar

Answer (score 0):

In my success page I have add this example:

```html
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '{/literal}{$idorder}{literal}', // Order ID.
'affiliation': '{/literal}{$lang.i_title}{literal}', // Affiliation or store name.
'revenue': '{/literal}{$total_sum}{literal}', // Grand Total.
'shipping': '{/literal}{$delivery_price}{literal}', // Shipping.
'tax': '0.00',
'currency': 'BGN' // local currency code.
});

{/literal}{if !empty($products)}{foreach from=$products key=k item=v}{literal}
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '{/literal}{$idorder}{literal}',
'name': '{/literal}{$v.name}{literal}',
'sku': '{/literal}{$v.idnumber}{literal}',
'category': '{/literal}{$v.idcategory}{literal}',
'price': '{/literal}{$v.product_price}{literal}',
'quantity': '{/literal}{$v.count}{literal}', 'currency': 'BGN'
});
{/literal}{/foreach}{/if}{literal}
ga('ecommerce:send');
```