# Clicks to element in div tag aren't being sent to Google Analytics

Tags: html, google-analytics

I am trying to get clicks on this div element/button to register in Google Analytics.  I've tried what's below as well as putting the onclick= part in the 'a' tag instead of in the div tag, but neither registers in the Google Analytics real time dashboard.

Here's the code with the onclick= in the div tag:

```
      <div class="pricing-box" id="box1">
          <img src="css/img/monitor32.png">
          <h3>SANDBOX</h3>
          <p class="box-title">Free up to .5GB </p>
          <div class="box-button" onclick=_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘button’, ’clicked’, ’sandbox’,, ’true’])><a class="button" href="mailto:foo@foo.com?Subject=Sandbox%20inquiry">Subscribe</a></div>
           <div class="spacer"></div> <div class="spacer"></div>
           <p class="box-desc">Some text.</p>
      </div><!--box 1 -->
```

Thanks for any feedback you can provide.

Comment: Please read this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333665/google-analytics-event-tracking-code/21466522#21466522. I just answered this question a few days ago man. You should check the forum and read some more before posting questions!

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me once and I added empty quotes for the parameter I didn't need to send:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'button', 'clicked', 'sandbox', '', 'true'])"
```

I found information that stated you could just add the comma `,` for the empty param and some information that you add empty quotes so I went with empty quotes and it worked.

It may not matter in some browsers but wrap the `_gaq.push` in quotes in the `onclick` attribute.

Also, make sure you are using the correct event tracking code for the version of Google Analytics that you have installed on the site. Google has been updating the tracking code as of late. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

One more thing - it could be that the `mailto` is being treated as an outbound link. Here is an article that may help: http://www.statstory.com/tracking-events-in-google-analytics/

If none of that works, install the [Google Analytics Debugger extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) for Chrome and make sure the tracking beacon is sent. The debugger will also show whether or not the event was tracked.